# "Invalid column name" when trying to insert data into database using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert new values into my database using visual studio and here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = dbconnectionstring;
conn.Open();

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data_ConfigInfo (TypeID, Name, ValidFromDate, ValidToDate, ValidFromSOP, ValidToSOP, Description)" +
                  "VALUES(@TypeID, @Name, @ValidFromDateTime, @ValidToDateTime, @ValidFromSOP, @ValidToSOP, @Description)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeID", Logg.TypeID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", Logg.Name);

if(Logg.ValidFrom.Equals(null)) {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidFromDateTime", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidFromDateTime", Logg.ValidFrom);
}

if (Logg.ValidTo.Equals(null))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidToDateTime", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidToDateTime", Logg.ValidFrom);
}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidFromSOP", Logg.ValidFromSOP);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidToSOP", Logg.ValidToSOP);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Logg.Description);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();
conn.dispose();
```

But at the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the error

> invalid column name for ValidToDateTime and ValidFromDateTime.

Both are datetime variables. I can't seem to find the error. Any ideas?

This is how my datatable looks

[image: Datatable structure]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your DB table has columns `ValidFromDateTime, ValidToDateTime`, but your column list in the `INSERT` statement has `ValidFromDate, ValidToDate`. Are you sure that it is not a typo when posting here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you forgot '@'?

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TypeID", Logg.TypeID);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", Logg.Name);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID", Logg.TypeID);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Logg.Name);
```